# JVLC libvlc error on windows 7

Tags: java, windows, ubuntu-12.04, jvlc

I have a problem with this java code doesn't execute :

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 
 Unable to load library    'libvlc': The specified module could not be found.

at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:127)
at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:170)
at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.<init>(Library.java:123)
at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:260)
at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:246)
at org.videolan.jvlc.internal.LibVlc.<clinit>(LibVlc.java:41)
at org.videolan.jvlc.JVLC.<init>(JVLC.java:45)
at net.jvlc.NewJFrame.<init>(NewJFrame.java:34)
at net.jvlc.Example.main(Example.java:10)
```

Comment: It would appear that you don't have the `libvlc` in a location that the JVLC API can find. Can you point us to the actually VLC library you are using

Comment: I'm using jna.jar and jvlc-core.jar and here is snippet             String[] arg = new String[4];
    arg[0] = "--intf=dummy";
    arg[1] = "--ignore-config";
    arg[2] = "--no-plugins-cache";
    arg[3] = "--plugin-path=plugins";
  
    this.jvlc = new JVLC(arg);

Comment: Yes, but "which" bindings are you using, I can find at least 3 distinct ones and may a couple more desides...

Comment: jna.jar Name: com/sun/jna/
Implementation-Title: com.sun.jna
Implementation-Vendor: JNA Development Team
Implementation-Version: 3.0.6 b2

Comment: jvlc-cor.jar Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.1
Created-By: 1.6.0_21-b06 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)

Comment: Unless you can provide a website to the authors and/or document, there's very little anybody can do...

Comment: The only information I can find is from the [videolan wiki page on Java Bindings](https://wiki.videolan.org/Java_bindings/) *"At the moment the JVLC project is dead, as there is no maintainer for it. If you want information on it, see the wiki history"*

Comment: That error is likely independent of the bindings used, it is a well documented problem about how to configure your environment correctly for JNA. There are multiple solutions, perhaps the simplest of them is to use NativeLibrary.addSearchPath("libvlc", "directory_that_contains_libvlc.dll"), or NativeLibrary.addSearchPath("vlc", "directory_that_contains_libvlc.so") to the start of your application.